# Display Table form with Eloquent Data Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an Object structure that is store in Eloquent Form

```
{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "L",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "M",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "S",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "White",
"item_size": "S",
"item_Quantity": "5",},
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to combine up all item_quantity which has the same **item_id** and **item_color** and Display in Table form like this.

```
ItemID ItemColor ItemSize  Quantity   Total
2         Black    L-M-S    5-5-5      15
2         White     S       5          5
```

In my research this is the nearest kind of solution but Im having trouble on displaying it in table form

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902541/add-array-values-of-same-array-keys-in-session
```

Comment: show us (your cycle in view?) what u have already tried

Comment: I already Got the right answer below Thank you guys :) @M0rtiis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$items = DB::table('item')
            ->select(DB::raw("item_id,item_color,GROUP_CONCAT(item_size SEPARATOR '-') as ItemSize,GROUP_CONCAT(item_Quantity SEPARATOR '-') as Quantity,sum(item_Quantity) as TOTAL"))
            ->groupBy('item_id','item_color')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I needed to upgrade from
"item_id": "1771",
"item_color": "Black",
"ItemSize": "L-S",
"Quantity": "10-5",
"Discount": "20",
"Total": "10"

To 

"item_id": "1771",
"item_color": "Black",
"ItemSizeQty1": "L-10",
"ItemSizeQty2": "S-5",
"Discount": "20",
"Total": "10"

Comment: why not make it another question with all requirements,there are a lot of people to be able to solve it and i will try my best.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,
Hi this is my new needed query thank you for your response,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964258/display-in-table-form-with-eloquent-or-raw-data-laravel @ConvertToInt32