# Group Concat that use Eloquent/Raw Laravel Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an Object structure that is store in Eloquent Form

```
{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "L",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "M",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "S",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "White",
"item_size": "S",
"item_Quantity": "5",},
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to combine up all item_quantity which has the same item_id and item_color and Display in Table form like this.

```
ItemID ItemColor    L-M-S     Total
2         Black     5-5-5      15
2         White         5      5
```

This is my Current Query

```
$items = DB::table('item')
            ->select(DB::raw("item_id,item_color,GROUP_CONCAT(item_size SEPARATOR '-') as ItemSize,GROUP_CONCAT(item_Quantity SEPARATOR '-') as Quantity,sum(item_Quantity) as TOTAL"))
            ->groupBy('item_id','item_color')
            ->get();
```

This is my first Query that is already solved:

[Display Table form with Eloquent Data Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780016/display-table-form-with-eloquent-data-laravel)

Comment: Hi this is my new Page of question, Thank you @ConvertToint32

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Table form with Eloquent Data Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780016/display-table-form-with-eloquent-data-laravel)

Comment: I needed another GroupConcat Query @Deena

Comment: @MartneyAcha how this differ from previous query?What is the change in output?

Comment: What I need for this query is to combine The Size and Qty to Display it in a single table <TD> @ConvertToInt32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$items = DB::table('item')
            ->select(DB::raw("item_id,item_color,GROUP_CONCAT(item_Quantity SEPARATOR '-') as `L-M-S`,sum(item_Quantity) as TOTAL"))
            ->groupBy('item_id','item_color')
            ->get();
```

I hope this is what you need , point to remember when using hypen in column name you have to make it wrapped with backticks.

Comment: You're the best, Man the hell why you're so good in this can I add you in FB ? Thank you man @ConvertToInt32