# Laravel fetch tags from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

```
   public function edit($id)
   {
    $blogs=Blog::findOrFail($id);
    $tags =$blogs->tags;
    $metaKeywords = $blogs->keywords;       
   return  view('admin.cms.blogs.edit_blog',compact('blogs','tags','metaKeywords'));
     }
```

And my view

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control product-tags"
 name="tags"
  @foreach($tags as $tag ) value="{{ $tag->tag_name }} "
 @endforeach>
```

I'm getting only a single valve text box,but there many tags in database
please suggest me an idea

Comment: You want to put all tags in one textbox, want to generated multiple text boxes?

Comment: hi anil ,I want to put all tags in one text box

Comment: Blog::findOrFail, which ORM? U can use ORM's concat function.

Comment: I'm using elquent ORM

Comment: You can use DB::raw('group_concat(tag)'), refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964258/group-concat-that-use-eloquent-raw-laravel-query and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847738/group-concat-laravel-eloquent to return one string for all tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control product-tags" name="tags"
value = "@foreach($tags as $tag ){{ $tag->tag_name }} @endforeach">
```

Comment: No it dint work,getting all tags together which is not correct.

Comment: this will loop through all of your tags which you get from controller. Make sure you have constrain to you eloquent query when getting tags.